# Retrieving Numbers with Specific Capabilities

Tags: php, rest, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

```
$numbers = $client->availablePhoneNumbers('US')->local->read(array(
"Capabilities" => "fax", 
"areaCode" => $areacode
));

$number = $client->incomingPhoneNumbers->create(array(
"phoneNumber" => $numbers[0]->phoneNumber,
"friendlyName" => "SpecialName",
"VoiceUrl" => "myurlcode",
"VoiceMethod" => "POST"
));


$twilionumber = $number->phoneNumber;
```

When I use the php code above to purchase a number, it is successful.
However, the twilio capabilities is not being recognized.
I need to be able to get only numbers available for Twilio Fax.

Based on Twilio's api documentation it should be working?
[Twilio Rest API Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-properties)

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you found the `"Capabilities"` thing

```
"Capabilities" => "fax", 
"areaCode" => $areacode
```

but I suggest you try instead:

```
"faxEnabled" => "true", 
"areaCode" => $areacode
```

---

It's mentioned here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/fax/receive#phone-number-setup

> If you don't have a fax-capable number, you'll need to purchase one.
>   You can either use the Available Phone Numbers REST API resource
>   (query with FaxEnabled=true) ,or Console Phone Numbers Search (check
>   the box to search for numbers with the Fax capability) to do so.

---

Also, for more insights you can read the source code of the helper library:

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/AvailablePhoneNumberCountry/LocalOptions.php